# F# Async Equivalent of Task.ContinueWith

Tags: f#, fody, continuewith, async-workflow

I have been implementing a `[<Trace>]` attribute for some of our larger .NET solutions that will allow configurable analytics to be easily added to any functions/methods that are considered important.  I'm using Fody and the [MethodBoundaryAspect](https://github.com/vescon/MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody) to intercept the entry and exit of each function and record  metrics.  This works well for synchronous functions, and for methods that return `Task` there is a workable solution with `Task.ContinueWith`, but for F# Async-returning functions, the `OnExit` from the MethodBoundaryAspect runs as soon as the Async is returned (rather than when the Async is actually executed).

In order to capture correct metrics for F# Async-returning functions, I was trying to come up with an equivalent solution to using `Task.ContinueWith`, but the closest thing I could think of was to create a new Async that binds the first one, runs the metric-capturing functions, and then returns the original result.  This is further complicated by the fact that the F# Async return value I'm intercepting is presented only as an `obj`, and I have to do everything thereafter reflectively, as there is no non-generic version of `Async` like there is with `Task` that I can use without knowing the exact return type.

My best solution so far looks roughly like this:

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics
open FSharp.Reflection
open MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody.Attributes

[<AllowNullLiteral>]
[<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method ||| AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)>]
type TraceAttribute () =
    inherit OnMethodBoundaryAspect()

    let traceEvent (args: MethodExecutionArgs) (timestamp: int64) =
        // Capture metrics here
        ()

    override __.OnEntry (args) =
        Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() |> traceEvent args

    override __.OnExit (args) =
        let exit () = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() |> traceEvent args
        match args.ReturnValue with
        | :? System.Threading.Tasks.Task as task ->
            task.ContinueWith(fun _ -> exit()) |> ignore             
        | other -> // Here's where I could use some help
            let clrType = other.GetType()
            if clrType.IsGenericType && clrType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<Async<_>> then
                // If the return type is an F# Async, replace it with a new Async that calls exit after the original return value is computed
                let returnType = clrType.GetGenericArguments().[0]
                let functionType = FSharpType.MakeFunctionType(returnType, typedefof<Async<_>>.MakeGenericType([| returnType |]))
                let f = FSharpValue.MakeFunction(functionType, (fun _ -> exit(); other))
                let result = typeof<AsyncBuilder>.GetMethod("Bind").MakeGenericMethod([|returnType; returnType|]).Invoke(async, [|other; f|]) 
                args.ReturnValue <- result
            else
                exit()
```

Unfortunately, this solution is not only quite messy, but I believe the reflective construction of an Async computation is adding a non-trivial amount of overhead, especially when I'm trying to trace functions that are called in a loop or have deeply-nested Async calls.  Is there a better way to achieve the same result of running a given function immediately after an Async computation is actually evaluated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @AMieres advice, I was able to update my `OnExit` method to correctly trace the async execution without so much overhead.  I think the bulk of the problem was actually in using the same instance of `AsyncBuilder`, which resulted in extra invocations of the async functions.  Here's the new solution:

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics
open FSharp.Reflection
open MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody.Attributes

[<AllowNullLiteral>]
[<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method ||| AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)>]
type TraceAttribute () =
    inherit OnMethodBoundaryAspect()
    static let AsyncTypeDef = typedefof<Async<_>>
    static let Tracer = typeof<TraceAttribute>
    static let AsyncTracer = Tracer.GetMethod("TraceAsync")

    let traceEvent (args: MethodExecutionArgs) (timestamp: int64) =
        // Capture metrics here
        ()

    member __.TraceAsync (asyncResult: Async<_>) trace =
        async {
            let! result = asyncResult
            trace()
            return result
        }

    override __.OnEntry (args) =
        Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() |> traceEvent args

    override __.OnExit (args) =
        let exit () = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() |> traceEvent args
        match args.ReturnValue with
        | :? System.Threading.Tasks.Task as task ->
            task.ContinueWith(fun _ -> exit()) |> ignore             
        | other -> 
            let clrType = other.GetType()
            if clrType.IsGenericType && clrType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = AsyncTypeDef then
                let generics = clrType.GetGenericArguments()
                let result = AsyncTracer.MakeGenericMethod(generics).Invoke(this, [| other; exit |])
                args.ReturnValue <- result
            else
                exit()
```

This seems to correctly trace the Async functions with significantly less overhead.  I did want to trace the total time from when the function was called rather than when the async actually started, so I left my `OnEntry` implementation the same.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is probably what you need:

```
let traceAsync (a:Async<_>) = async {
    trace() // trace start of async
    let! r = a
    trace() // trace end of async
    return r
}
```

Consider that when a function returns an async that does not mean the async has started. An async is more like a function, it can be invoked several times or none at all. Which means you need to check if the return value is an Async also in your `OnEntry` method.

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track.  I actually wanted to capture the entire time from when the function was called to when the async execution completed, so I left my `OnEntry` behavior as it was, but using a function like this and calling it reflectively in my `OnExit` was definitely an improvement.